# Parallax type effect without javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, scroll, parallax

If you take a look at this site (if you haven't already):

http://riotdesign.eu/

I'm wondering how to achieve the effect of the content slowly covering the image while the image is also slowly receding.. 
Everywhere I read it says that this kind of thing can only be done using javascript.. But I don't see any javascript being implemented in their code.

Comment: There are 10 script tags in the `head` alone - they're definitely using javascript

Comment: there are many scripts http://riotdesign.eu/assets/js/main.js?v=3

Comment: Well, I see that. I am not that dumb :). But what I don't see is a parallax script or anything that I have seen in any tutorials.

Comment: Actually, they are using JavaScript to modify attributes of the image on scroll. If you look at the HTML of the `<img>` element using some browser developer tools, you can see that the inline `top` style is altered whenever you scroll the window - something not achievable without JavaScript. So unfortunately, this is not a JavaScript-free implementation of parallax scrolling.